# SOQL Count with multiple Where clauses

Tags: salesforce, soql

I am trying to count all the results that match multiple Where conditions in Salesforce. All these Where conditions exist under the same object that I am selecting from. It seems like it should be a simply query but my SQL and SOQL experience is limited.

Here's my code right now:

```
SELECT count() FROM Account
WHERE Success__c='yes'
AND Active__c='true'
AND Days__c>'30'
AND Days__c<'37'
```

Comment: how is it not working?

Comment: I should have clarified: I want to pull this data into Geckoboard but Geckoboard is telling me there is an error with my SOQL. If there's nothing wrong with it, then I'm guessing it is something on their end.

Comment: Have you tried this query in the Developer Console (Query Editor section) ?  The first line works.  I can't test the rest as I don't have your custom fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be useful to see the actual error message, but at a guess, you have quotes around things that shouldn't have them, e.g. you want

```
SELECT count() FROM Account
WHERE Success__c = 'yes'
AND Active__c = true
AND Days__c > 30
AND Days__c < 37
```

Also there are tools like SoqlX, the Force.com IDE and Workbench that'll let you run queries, so if Geckoboard is hiding the actual error message, you can work through getting a good query in one of these tools first.

Comment: Hey, looks like it was the quotes. Something super basic, didn't even consider it. Thanks!